# Unable to install phpmyadmin on CentOS with LEMP

Tags: nginx

I followed the following steps while installing phpmyadmin.

1-Enabled EPEL repo

2-Downloaded and extracted phpmyadmin to /usr/share/

3-Copied config.sample.inc.php into config.inc.php file

4-Created /etc/nginx/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf and added

```
server {
listen       8080;                          # listen port
server_name  localhost;                     # Server name
location / {
    root   /usr/share/phpmyadmin;           # Document root
    index index.php  index.html index.htm;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    root           /usr/share/phpmyadmin;   # Document root
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
}
```

5-Restarted nginx, to find that localhost:8080 is a blank page.

Please point out the right way its done. My [source](http://www.krizna.com/centos/install-phpmyadmin-nginx-centos-6/).

Comment: from nginx log:
    4855#0: *3 open() "/usr/share/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /phpmyadmin HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080"

Comment: That seems pretty obvious.

Comment: Yes, but I fixed the folder name, even put the folder in document root. It still isn't working. It would be great if anyone could point me to a correct tutorial.

Comment: Administration panels are off topic.